# Store a video from iPad2 in a Django model

Tags: django, video, django-models, ipad-2

I need to store a video taken on iPad2 in a Django model.  What is the best format to store the video in and what type of Django model field?

I want to show the video on a website using HTML5 (avoid flash if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it in MPEG-4, and use a [FileField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield) to store it.

Comment: Due to browser vendors not agreeing on a single format you'll need to support multiple formats if you want to support all browsers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video  Ogg Theora and/or WebM have the widest availability across browser vendors at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Ogg Theora and [`FileField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield).